# git log to see just the new entries

Tags: git

I want to use git log to see all the new entries in my file but just this.
To explain I have a file that can be updated by different persons in the same git. Once a week I want to see all the new lines in this file. I can use the command

```
git log aaf5ccs -p --stat src/languages
```

that return to me something like that

```
commit 3881c6a50327520f25ec533b0a20a4a6a84a1656
Author: stephane <stephane@stephane-VirtualBox.(none)>
Date:   Tue Sep 15 15:31:46 2015 -0500

actualise language.
---
src/languages/en-US/common.lang.json |    2 +-
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/src/languages/en-US/common.lang.json b/src/languages/en-US/common.lang.json
index f841841..bd66cf5 100644
--- a/src/languages/en-US/common.lang.json
+++ b/src/languages/en-US/common.lang.json
@@ -159,7 +159,7 @@
      "Bug_Report": "Bug Report",
      "Bulk_Data_Export": "Bulk Data Export",
      "Buy": "Buy",
 -    "Buy_PlanName_plan": "Buy {PlanName} plan",
 +    "Buy_PlanName_plan": "Buy {planName} plan",
      "Buy_now": "Buy now",
      "CARD_INFO": "CARD INFO",
      "CARD_INFO_colon": "CARD INFO:",
```

but I just want the line with the +:

```
+    "Buy_PlanName_plan": "Buy {planName} plan",
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your command with `grep`:

```
git log aaf5ccs -p --stat src/languages | grep '^ +'
```